# error when adding GPS library admob

Tags: gps, admob, extends, implements

the error is :

The type AdListener cannot be a superinterface of FlyingPanda; a superinterface must be an interface

```
   public class FlyingPanda  extends Activity implements AdListener {
```

where is the problem i try to replace the implements kyeword by extends but the error still there.

need you help plz

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/play-migration),

You can no longer implement AdListener from your Activity or class

You can use it as an anonymous inner class:

**For Interstitial ads:**

```
 interstitalAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
  public void onAdLoaded() {}
  public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorcode) {}
  // Only implement methods you need.
});
```

**And for banner ads**

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
  public void onAdLoaded() {}
  public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorcode) {}
  // Only implement methods you need.
});
```